# Custom razor helper with IHtmlHelper reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I was playing with asp.net core and was trying to migrate my helpers to it. I've injected my own helper to the views, but I needed to access the default IHtmlHelper (I do no want to extend the HtmlHelper).

So, I built my constructor like this, to get the concrete IHtmlHelper from IoC.

```
public FWHtmlHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
        this._htmlHelper = htmlHelper;
}
```

The thing is, when I tried to access the helper, I got this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Must call 'Contextualize' method before using this HtmlHelper instance.

So, how can I create my own helper and access the View html helper instance?

*Edit, as requested:

added to the container

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IFWHtmlHelper<>), typeof(FWHtmlHelper<>));
```

injected it into the view

```
@inject IFWHtmlHelper<TModel> FWHtml
```

Then, I created an extension for my helper

```
public static TagBuilder Example<TModel, TValue>(this IFWHtmlHelper<TModel> fwHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating/registering this class? Could you provide sample code that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Well, I'm adding my interface to the IoC with "services.AddTransient(typeof(IFWHtmlHelper<>), typeof(FWHtmlHelper<>));" and injecting it into the view @inject IFWHtmlHelper<TModel> FWHtml. Then, I created an extension for my helper with public static TagBuilder Example<TModel, TValue>(this IFWHtmlHelper<TModel> fwHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) {}

Comment: As the error says, an `IHtmlHelper` only makes sense when used within the context of a view and thus neds a `ViewContext` to be provided by calling its `Contextualize` method. Why not creating the extension directly over `IHtmlHelper` or creating a tag helper?

Comment: My helper extensions have the same signatures as the IHtmlHelper (i.e. EditorFor, TextboxFor etc). So I cannot create the extensions over IHtmlHelper.
As for the tag helpers, they do not make sense for all my helpers. For instance, i'll use tag helpers for my custom forms, since its basically a form tag with a few custom tags. But for controls that generates a lot of inner html, I find it very weird to add a tag helper for a DIV to create a pagination grid.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem.  Since MVC adds IHtmlHelper as a transient scoped dependency, we don't get the same IHtmlHelper as the view is getting.  MVC contextualizes the other instance, but not the private your class is getting.

My solution was to Contextualize the private (transient) IHtmlHelper that DI passed in.  To do this, implement IViewContextAware, and then pass that contexualization on to the private IHtmlHelper so it's wired up like it wants

```
    public partial class MyHelper : IViewContextAware {        
        public MyHelper(IHtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
            this.Html = htmlHelper;                        
        }
        public IHtmlHelper Html {
            get;
            private set;
        }

        void IViewContextAware.Contextualize(ViewContext viewContext) {
            if (Html is IViewContextAware) {
                ((IViewContextAware)Html).Contextualize(viewContext);
            }
        }
    }
```